# why do we need to find file size using seekg and tellg

Tags: c++

I have rudimentary question, why do we have to use seekg to move the pointer to the end of the stream then use a tellg then move the pointer back to the beginning.
I understand that it is to find the filesize but why do we need the file size?

```
int myFileSize;
std::fstream myFile;
myFile.open(myFileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
if (myFile.is_open())
{
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    myFileSize = myFile.tellg();
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    myFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I have no clue what you'll need the file size for. _We_ don't need it in general.

Comment: I can *imagine* all sorts of reasons you might want the file size. But this works a lot better if you *tell* us.

Comment: Imagine you want to load the content of a file into a buffer and allocate this buffer beforehand. For this you must know the size of the file.

Comment: You should post the code where you use `myFileSize` as well.

Comment: "why do we need the file size?" - You don't need the file size. And if you do, you'll know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no guarantee that you can find the file size
using `seekg` and `tellg`; the return type of `tellg` isn't
guaranteed to be convertable to an integral type, and even if it
is convertable, there's no guarantee that the numeric value
represents anything real.  This technique happens to work under
Unix, and under Windows *if* the file has been opened in binary
mode.  For some definition of "file size", and generally, only
if the file is imbued with the "C" locale.

Why is this so?  The reason starts with how you define file
size.  In most such cases, the user seems to want the number of
`char` he can read before encountering end of file.  In a more
general context, the definition would be the number of bytes the
file occupies on the disk.  And most systems provide no way of
determining either of those, at least not directly.  Under Unix
(and under Windows, if the file is opened in binary mode), the
file size reported by the system does correspond to the number
of `char` you can read, provided the locale imbued in the
`filestream` does no code translation, or translates the codes
one to one.  (This is guaranteed for the "C" and the "POSIX"
locales.)

C++ still tries to support most platforms, and certainly tries
to support mainframes.  For this reason, it doesn't standardize
functions which cannot be implemented on some platforms.  C++11
introduced the concept of "conditionally supported features",
however; perhaps a proposal for a conditionally supported file
size function would be acceptable.  To date, I'm not aware of
anyone who has made such a proposal, however.

Comment: Thanks. Does it work the same way as extracting a file? must we always convert it to binary?

Comment: @MichaelGoh You can open any file in binary mode or in text mode. It's not a conversion.

Comment: @molbdnilo On most systems.  It's not guaranteed, however, and on some mainframes or earlier systems, a file written in text mode could not be opened in binary and vice versa.